# How can I verify if a string is a valid float?

Tags: python, string, validation, numbers

What I want to do is to verify if a string is numeric -- a float -- but I haven't found a string property to do this. Maybe there isn't one. I have a problem with this code:

```
N = raw_input("Ingresa Nanometros:");
if ((N != "") and (N.isdigit() or N.isdecimal())):
    N = float(N);
    print "%f" % N;
```

As you can see, what I need is to take only the numbers, either decimal or float. `N.isdecimal()` does not resolve the problem that I have in mind.

Comment: The Python mantra is *'Ask for forgiveness, not permission.'* - try it, and catch the exceptions if it goes wrong.

Comment: If you want to know why your code doesn't work: `N.isdigit()` is true if every character in `N` is a digit. That isn't true for `3.14`. You're asking "Is every character a digit, or is every character a decimal?" when you want to ask "Is each character either a digit or a decimal", which would be spelled `all(ch.isdigit() or ch.isdecimal() for ch in N)`. Of course that still won't work for, say, `-3.14` or other perfectly valid `float`s. That's one of the many reasons that "Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission" is the "One Way To Do It"—but it's still worth understanding `isdigit`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
try:
    N = float(N)
except ValueError:
    pass
except TypeError:
    pass
```

This tries to convert `N` to a `float`. However, if it isn't possible (because it isn't a number), it will `pass` (do nothing).

I suggest you read about [`try` and `except` blocks](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).

You could also do:

```
try:
    N = float(N)
except (ValueError, TypeError):
    pass
```

Comment: If `N` is `None` then you will get `TypeError` and your code will blow up. Use `float(N or '')`

Comment: @YevgenYampolskiy Ah, that's true. I added in `except TypeError` to avoid that.

Comment: `except (ValueError, TypeError) as e: pass` at least

Comment: hey! thanks a lot, this solve my problem.  i'm a ansi c and asm programmer but i'm enjoying so much python :D